# Dropped variables due to multicollinearity

Tags: regression, stata, multicollinearity

I've encountered an interesting result when I was performing two following regression in Stata:

```
regress y v1 v2 ... v13, robust
regress y v1* v2* ... v13*, robust
```

where $v_1$* is the growth of $v_1$, and $v_2$* is the growth of $v_2$, defined by $v^*_{1,t} = \frac{v{_{1,t}}}{v_{1,t-1}}$ - 1.

$v_1$ and $v_2$ is related as following:

$v_1$ = $w_3$ - $w_4$, while $v_2$ = $w_3$ - $w_5$.

When I run the aforementioned regression, Stata drops $v_1$* in the second regression, but Stata does not drop $v_1$ nor $v_2$ in first regression. I understand that variable that contains the same information is dropped in the regression because of multicollinearity, but I don't understand why the variable is dropped only for second regression. I'm thinking that variable in the first regression should be dropped because they are linearly related, but it seems that opposite is happening in my case.

What is the statistical reason for such outcome?

EDIT: To give more background on this question, $y$ is the growth rate of investment, while $v_1$ and $v_2$ is different financial indicators. This regression has year fixed effect, and there are other independent variables that I've excluded from the lines above for simplicity. I also believe that other variables, and $w_4$ and $w_5$ specifically, are related to one another, though not perfectly related.

NEW EDIT: After looking into this issue, I've found another interesting property in this problem. I've tried to see if $v_1$* is a linear combination of all the other variables, and as suspected, it is. However, $v_1$ is ALSO a linear combination of all the other variables, but Stata has not dropped $v_1$. I suspect that it is dependent on how Stata omits variables that are correlated. While it appears sort of off-topic now with new information, are there any insights as to why Stata is behaving in such a way?

Comment: Both your models seem rather obscure. Can you explain how they relate to your scientific question?

Comment: V1 and V2 are actually not linearly related in terms of the predictors of the model, so they are not necessarily colinear (i.e., the matrix may be full rank). If V4 and V5 are independent, then V1 and V2 contain totally different information (except due to their imperfect correlation with V3). So you shouldn't expect your first equation to suffer from multicolinearity. It's possible the growth is colinear but the variables themselves aren't.

Comment: I've edited to give more information. After thinking about it for a while, my guess is that multicollinearity problem appears on second regression because unit of y is growth as well. How can I validate this, or disprove my guess?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1375383-dropping-variables-in-regression-due-to-collinearity Telling people about cross-posting is polite in any forum

Comment: Both threads are currently active, this one and that on Statalist. You created both; your responsibility to both remains.

Comment: I apologize that I didn't know the culture of cross-posting prior to today. I'll remember to link the question next time if I ever do so.

Comment: The good news is that not much explanation is needed if you think it through. Unless everyone is monitoring all possible forums simultaneously (manifestly not the case) telling people about other threads is a good idea, so that (a) people can find answers of interest (b) people don't post an answer already posted elsewhere. People not knowing what they don't know is not a conscious loss, but people finding out that they have posted something already said (or asking for clarification of what has already been explained) is likely to be irritating.